# Django - Invalid block tag..'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having trouble loading this. I'm fairly new to python and it's formatting. I've checked previous questions where it seems to be a syntax error but I can't see any formatting issues. The code is taken straight from the Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial06/

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li></ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You start a for loop with `{% for question in latest_question_list %}` but you have no `{% endfor %}` tag.

Comment: Incidetnally it looks like you've taken the code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/, but the endfor tag *is* present there, so you have presumably (accidentally) deleted it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Tom Dalton,
Issue was the missing {% endear %}.